# Allow public access to only one php script and deny the rest

Tags: php, ajax, http-status-code-403

This is the problem:

I have this website with this structure:

```
php (folder)
css (folder)
js (folder)
index.php
```

In index.php, I use the `include()` php function to include the files who are inside the php folder, and I do the same in other files who are inside the php folder.

I have an .htaccess file in the php folder with this content: `deny from all`, so if I try to access one file in the php folder from the browser, I will get an 403 (Forbidden) error (this is fine)

The problem is that I need to make an Ajax request from a js file (in the js folder), and when I want to do this, I get the same 403 error. I tried to put in .htaccess:

```
<Files saveComment.php>
    allow from all
</Files>
```

and now it works, but anyone could access the file from the browser and mess with my database (the file save "comments" in the database)

Any help? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

With your setup I would recommend routing all requests to your `index.php` file. So instead of `saveComment.php` you would have `/comments/save` which in turn internally execute the contents of `saveComment.php`

The reason for that is because once you set a `deny` to a directory using `.htaccess` then it will apply to all sub directories.

Comment: I do not think it will secure the database.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I'm not too sure I understand what you meant by that.

Comment: Feels that he wants to secure his code that bad people wont post bad stuff to his soft (And now he does that with htaccess).

Comment: Oh I see, then yeah you would need to have security checks within the script itself to make sure the incoming data is valid.

Comment: @Samer you said: "you would need to have security checks within the script itself to make sure the incoming data is valid".. how can I do that? thanks

Comment: You will need to validate the data yourself. In essence, any script that take input from a form will need to validate it's data.